# What is a difference between "Make X smile." and "Make X smiley."?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

My approximate recognition is

- Make X smile.

  ```
  Mr. Yamada who is my friend always says Japanese joke, which makes everybody smile.
  ```

  A state that X laughs at something.
- Make X smiley.

  ```
  A gift from Santa Claus makes my son smiley.
  ```

  A state the X is with a smile.

Is my recognition correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Smile** is a verb (in this sentence.  It can also be a noun, but here it is a verb).
**Smiley** is an adjective, [meaning "having a smile", or "cheerful"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smiley).

So "Makes him smile" means "Makes him perform the action of smiling."  (Not "laughing"!  That's different!)
"Make him smiley" means "Make him display the characteristic *smiley*."

So there is not much difference in meaning.  My advice would be to say "Makes him smile" or "Makes him *happy*".  [*Smile* is much more common than *smiley*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=smile%2Csmiley&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csmile%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmiley%3B%2Cc0) (in fact, Google Ngrams does not find *any* occurrence of "makes him smiley"!), and also *smiley* usually means an emoji or **:-)** or **(⌒‿⌒)**.

Comment: Sound advice indeed. A couple of decades ago I'd have said adjectival ***smiley*** was at the very least "unusual / stylised". Today, given the widespread *noun* usage, I'd say it's even less likely to be used naturally in contexts like ***a smiley child*** (which would put me in mind of a child who uses lots of smilies in his txt msgs, rather than one who smiles a lot).

Comment: She's very smiley. To be smiley is very common. I would not advise: make someone smiley, though.

Comment: "Smiley" is also a **noun**. The most famous smiley is `:)`. In general, smileys are character sequences resembling a face, expressing emotions. They're the precursor to emoji's but are traditionally tilted to the left.

Comment: @stangdon Thank you very much for your kind instruction. Google Books Ngram Viewer is new to me. It looks good. thanks. By the way, Japanese call (⌒‿⌒) "Kaomoji" ("Kao" means face).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, @Lambie, @MSalters, Thank you very much for your comment. It helps me, It makes me happy. (人´∀`)

Comment: @mf_ham: Don't forget there's often a considerable difference between *He makes me smile* and *He makes me happy*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I see. I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

> Y makes X smile.

Something (Y) causes person (X) to smile. (Not necessarily laugh)

> Y makes X smiley.

Something (Y) causes person (X) to feel cheerful and smile often.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I learned a nuance.